# Invalid use of incomplete type - why no error in this case?

Tags: c++, templates, incomplete-type

I am confused about why my code is not producing the error `invalid use of incomplete type`, while all the reading I have done about this error suggests it should.
<sub><sup>The question stemmed from this error showing up (as expected) in the part of my code with a similar structure, but I can not reproduce it in a *small* example (please see *disclaimer* at the end of the question).</sup></sub>

Summary of what I am trying to do:

- I have a structure (`Tree`), and I want to assign different objects of base type `First` to it.
- Concrete implementations of `First` have different return values, so two levels of indirection are used:
- `First` is an abstract base class, and `First *` are used to handle different concrete instances.
- `template <typename Type> class TypedFirst : public First` is an abstract type that defines the function with return type `Type`.
- Finally `ConcreteFirstX` are concrete specializations of `TypedFirst<Type>`.

In `tree.tpp`, why does the call to `new TF(this)` *not* produce the `invalid use of incomplete type` error? (the spot is marked in the code) I think the error should be there because, while `TF` is a template, when I using `ConcreteFirstA`, the `tree.tpp` is not aware of it (it does not include `concretefirsta.h` or even `first.h`, it *only* forward declares `First`)

The full, compilable and runnable code for this example can be found [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ng246TnL). Here, I will exclude `#define` guards and similar things, for brevity. The code is as follows:

```
// tree.h
class First;
class Tree{
  public:
    Tree() {}
    ~Tree() {}
    template<class TF> // where TF is a ConcreteFirst
    void addFirstToTree();
  private:
    std::map<std::string, First *> firstCollection; // <- "First"'s here
};
#include "tree.tpp"

// tree.tpp
#include "tree.h"

template <class TF> // where TF is a ConcreteFirst
void Tree::addFirstToTree(){
  this->firstCollection[TF::name] = new TF(this); // <--- Why does this work?
  //                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^      
}
```

---

```
// first.h
class Tree;
class First{
  public:
    static const std::string name;
    First(const Tree *baseTree) : myTree(baseTree) {}
    virtual ~First();
  protected:
    const Tree *myTree;
};

template <typename Type> class TypedFirst : public First{
  public:
    static const std::string name;
    TypedFirst(const Tree *baseTree) : First(baseTree) {}
    Type &value() {return this->_value;}
  private:
    Type _value;
};
#include "first.tpp"

// first.tpp
#include "first.h"
template <typename Type>
const std::string TypedFirst<Type>::name = "default typed";

// first.cpp
#include "first.h"
First::~First() {}
const std::string First::name = "default";
```

---

```
// concretefirsta.h
#include "first.h"
class ConcreteFirstA : public TypedFirst<int>{
  public:
    static const std::string name;
    ConcreteFirstA(const Tree *baseTree) : TypedFirst<int>(baseTree) {}
    ~ConcreteFirstA() {}
};

// concretefirsta.cpp
#include "concretefirsta.h"
const std::string ConcreteFirstA::name = "firstA";
```

Finally, the code that brings all that together and makes the (in)appropriate function calls:

```
// main.cpp
#include "tree.h"
#include "first.h"
#include "concretefirsta.h"

int main(){
  Tree *myTree = new Tree();
  myTree->addFirstToTree<ConcreteFirstA>(); // <-- here! why is this working?
  delete myTree;
  return 0;
}
```

---

**DISCLAIMER** This question was actually motivated by a bigger problem I had, that I deemed too big and unanswerable in Stack Overflow format. Even though I originally tried asking about it, the question was closed as too broad and I am now trying to salvage it by asking only a part of the question.

My problem is that *I keep getting the error* in a piece of code with identical structure to this one: but, I can not reproduce it in a small example.

Thus, I am asking **why the following piece of code is *not* producing the error** `invalid use of incomplete type` (as I would expect), and I hope that will help me understand and solve my actual problem.

Please, do not tell me that this is a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377): I know I am not asking about my actual problem, because I (and the community) deemed it too big for this format.

Comment: Have you tried 'subtractively' cutting out the code until the compile error goes away? The other technique is to preprocessor the problematic src file and start stubbing out large swath of code until it compiles without that error. I'm assuming you're using some kind of version control for easy rollback.

Answer (score 2):

`main.cpp` includes `tree.h`, which contains (indirectly) the problematic `addFirstToTree()` template, and `concretefirsta.h`, which contains the definition of `ConcreteFirstA`.

Later in `main.cpp`, `addFirstToTree()` is instantiated for the `ConcreteFirstA` type:

```
myTree->addFirstToTree<ConcreteFirstA>(); // <-- here! why is this working?
```

This is the point where the compiler needs to know enough enough about the types used as template parameters to be able to compiler `addFirstToTree()`. And it does know enough. `ConcreteFirstA` is a complete type here, since `concretefirsta.h` got included and contains the class definition.

---

Earlier on in `tree.tpp` where `addFirstToTree()` gets defined, `ConcreteFirstA` is not defined yet, but that doesn't matter. The compiler sees a template and doesn't know for what template parameters that template will be instantiated later on. Any functions/... that depend on a template parameter ("dependent names") cannot be resolved without knowing for which parameters the template will be instantiated, so that name lookup/... is put off until later.

Once the template is instantiated and the compiler resolves all the dependent names and compiles the template for the specific template parameters. Since `ConcreteFirstA` is not an incomplete type at that point this works without errors.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply, I've fallen sick and only now had some time to look over the answer. TY for the answer. So basically, just to clarify, the other marked spot in my code `new TF(this)` (in `tree.tpp`) is working despite `tree.tpp` _not_ including `concretefirsta.h` because in only gets compiled after everything gets included in `main.cpp`?

Answer (score 1):

Because templates are not compiled until you instanciate them with concrete arguments.

When the compiler comes to the line:

```
myTree->addFirstToTree<ConcreteFirstA>();
```

it compiles the function `addFirstToTree` for the first time with the argument `ConcreteFirstA`, which is a completely known type there.

See [cplusplus.com - Templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)

> They are compiled on demand, meaning that the code of a template function is not compiled until an instantiation with specific template arguments is required. At that moment, when an instantiation is required, the compiler generates a function specifically for those arguments from the template.